# How can I plot these random variables? (Half Cauchy, Horseshoe, Laplace, Normal)

Tags: r

I want to plot these random variables in R but my result is this one:

```
    compare_priors <- function(scale = 1, df_t = 2, xlim = c(-6, 6),ylim=c(0,50)) {
  dt_loc_scale <- function(x, df, location, scale) {
    1/scale * dt((x - location)/scale, df)
  }
  dlaplace <- function(x, location, scale) {
    0.5 / scale * exp(-abs(x - location) / scale)
  }
  dhos<-function (x, location, scale, log = FALSE){
      dens <- dnorm(x, 0, location * 25, log = log) 
  }
  stat_dist <- function(dist, ...) {
    ggplot2::stat_function(ggplot2::aes_(color = dist), ...)
  }
  ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(x = xlim), ggplot2::aes(x)) +
    stat_dist("normal", size = 0.8, fun = dnorm,
              args = list(mean = 0, sd = scale)) +
    stat_dist("student_t", size = 0.8, fun = dt_loc_scale,
              args = list(df = df_t, location = 0, scale = scale)) +
    stat_dist("cauchy", size = 0.8, linetype = 2, fun = dcauchy,
              args = list(location = 0, scale = scale)) +
    stat_dist("laplace", size = 0.8, linetype = 2, fun = dlaplace,
              args = list(location = 0, scale = scale))+
    stat_dist("horseshoe", size = 0.8, linetype = 2, fun = dhos,
              args = list(location = 0, scale = scale)) 
}
# Cauchy has fattest tails, followed by student_t, laplace, and normal
compare_priors()
```

[image: plot of distributions]

I want to arrive at this result:

[image]

Comment: not clear to me why your definition of the horseshoe prior/distribution seems to be just a Normal distribution with sd = 25*location ... ? (Also, that's not a "half" cauchy as suggested in your title ...)

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I wanted to show the results and try to understand how to improve them.